How to unwrap an async or sync generator
I want to unwrap an async generator or a sync generator and get it's inner return type.
i.e. I'm looking for an equivalent of Awaited that's used for promises.
For promises I used to:
async function foo() {
}

let returnValue: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof foo>>;

For generators, I'm looking for:
async function* foo() {
}

function* bar() {
}

let returnValue: ???<ReturnType<typeof foo | typeof bar>>;


es2015.iterable contains the Generator type you could use to infer the yield values:
function* foo() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
}

function* bar() {
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
}

type GeneratorValue<G extends (...arg: any[]) => any> = ReturnType<G> extends Generator<infer X> ? X : never;

type fooG = GeneratorValue<typeof foo | typeof bar> // 1 | 2 | 3 | 4

Playground
Typing an async generator using this doesn't work neither I could easily extend an AsyncGenerator type from existing interfaces, but seems that's possible somehow.

You can implement your utility types similarly to how ReturnType is implemented, except instead of inferring the whole return type, you infer the type arguments to the AsyncGenerator and Generator generic types (since that's what generator/async generator functions return when you look at their declarations in TypeScript):
type GenYieldType<T extends (...args: any) => Generator<any, any, any>> =
  T extends (...args: any) => Generator<infer R, any, any> ? R : never;

type AsyncGenYieldType<T extends (...args: any) => AsyncGenerator<any, any, any>> =
  T extends (...args: any) => AsyncGenerator<infer R, any, any> ? R : never

Let's test it out:
async function* foo() { yield "a"; yield "b"; }
type FooYield = AsyncGenYieldType<typeof foo>
//   ^? type FooYield = "a" | "b"
    
function* bar() { yield "c"; yield "d"; }
type BarYield = GenYieldType<typeof bar>
//   ^? type BarYield = "c" | "d"

Looks good.
Playground link to code
